# Bitcoin Core Onion Service created unexpectedly

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor

Why is Bitcoin Core onion service created when I have not mentioned anything related in `bitcoin.conf`?

bitcoin.conf in Windows (data directory):

```
prune=2048
```

bitcoin.conf in Fedora (running bitcoind)

```
prune=2048
datadir=/mnt/hgfs/mainnet
```

/mnt/hgfs/mainnet -> E:\Core-Backup\bitcoin-mainnet (Shared folder in VM)

```
ls /mnt/hgfs/mainnet
anchors.dat   blocks      fee_estimates.dat     peers.dat
banlist.dat   chainstate  mempool.dat           settings.json
bitcoin.conf  debug.log   onion_v3_private_key
```

Logs:

```
2021-06-12T01:19:40Z tor: Got service ID 64randomchars, advertising service 64randomchars.onion:8333
2021-06-12T01:19:40Z msghand thread start
2021-06-12T01:19:40Z addcon thread start
2021-06-12T01:19:40Z net thread start
2021-06-12T01:19:40Z AddLocal(64randomchars.onion:8333,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin Core will construct a Tor hidden service by default, if a Tor control port is found and Tor is configured to allow it.

You can use `torcontrol=0` to disable it.